# Calculate difference (in hours) between two times in PHP

Tags: php

I need to calculate the difference between two times in hours. For example, the difference between 08:00:00 and 09:30:00 would be 1.5 hours.

I'm using the code below:

```
$time1 = '08:00:00';
$time2 = '09:30:00';
$difference = $time2 - $time1;
echo $difference;
```

Instead of getting 1.5 back as I'd expect, I'm getting 1. I'm sure this is a time formatting issue that someone can easily advise me on. Hopefully... :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try my code

```
<?php
$time1 = strtotime('08:00:00');
$time2 = strtotime('09:30:00');
$difference = round(abs($time2 - $time1) / 3600,2);
echo $difference;
```

Note: The code above will round to minutes.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
    $time1 = '08:00:00';
    $time2 = '09:30:00';
    $array1 = explode(':', $time1);
    $array2 = explode(':', $time2);

    $minutes1 = ($array1[0] * 60.0 + $array1[1]);
    $minutes2 = ($array2[0] * 60.0 + $array2[1]);

    echo $diff = $minutes1 - $minutes2.' Minutes';
?>
```

Comment: It's good to have code broken down like this, but it would be good to explain how this resolves the rounding issue in the question.

Comment: When you explode the time string it will have a new string, not an array, so this code will cause an error

Comment: `$minutes1 - $minutes2` appears to be backwards.  Perhaps you intended to take the absolute value?

Comment: Note: this would not take DST changes into account, as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664921/208273) does.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use <kbd>diff</kbd> to calculate two time difference

```
$time1 = new DateTime('08:00:00');
$time2 = new DateTime('09:30:00');
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);

echo $interval->format('%H:%I');
```