# How to make time difference between two datetimes?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to return the difference between two datetime objects.

I tried this but is not working.
Whats wrong?

```
<?php //php 7.0.8

    $a='2018-12-05 09:00:00';
    $b='2018-12-05 15:00:00';

    $time1 = new DateTime($a);
    $time2 = new DateTime($b);

    $interval = $time1->diff($time2);
    echo $interval->format('H:i');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Each format character must be prefixed by a percent sign (%).

```
echo $interval->format('%H:%i');
```

Comment: it show odd stuff like 20:2 and 1:0 . how can I do it like 20:20 or 01:00?

Comment: @FabioAraujo take a look at PHP documentation, there are alternative formatting options, including leading zeros: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: @FabioAraujo you just need `I` instead of `i`.

Comment: %H just allow to show time between 0 and 23, there is any hour representation to show any hours you want 0 to infinit?? This is an app to log worked time and I need it to show in hours.

Comment: @FabioAraujo There are plenty answers on StackOverflow on how to find time difference in hours, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664921/586678