# Show Estimated Delivery for Products in select Taxonomy in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently using the snippet below to show estimated delivery on my single product pages. I need help making a few changes to the code;

1. I currently have a custom taxonomy ***(Available now)*** and would like to
   modify the code to show for only products with that taxonomy
2. Change the output notice to show eg. (***Ready for delivery between 4
   Nov & 7 Nov when you order within [hours left before end of day].)***
3. **Hide** the notice when when the item is ***out of stock***

---

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'delivery_estimate' );
    
function delivery_estimate() {
   date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Tallinn' );  
    
   // if FRI/SAT/SUN delivery will be MON
   if ( date( 'N' ) >= 5 ) {
      $del_day = date( "l jS F", strtotime( "next tuesday" ) );
      $order_by = "Monday";
   } 
    
   // if MON/THU after 4PM delivery will be day after tomorrow
   elseif ( date( 'H' ) >= 16 ) {
      $del_day = date( "l jS F", strtotime( "tomorrow + 1 day" ) );
      $order_by = "tomorrow";
   } 
    
   // if MON/THU before 4PM delivery will be TOMORROW
   else {
      $del_day = date( "2 jS F", strtotime( "tomorrow" ) );
      $order_by = "today";
   }
 
   $html = "<br><div class='woocommerce-message' style='clear:both'>Order by 4PM {$order_by} for delivery on {$del_day}</div>";
    
   echo $html;
}
```

Comment: About 1. why not put products you want to hide either out of stock go to woo settings and set it to hide products out of stock https://prnt.sc/1y5agdp . Another option is on product page in Catalog visibility you can hide products https://prnt.sc/1y5aqzj . Avoid complicating your shop with code that will do the same.

Comment: Products that are out of stock are set to back order. So hiding them is not an option. Hiding out of stock products also hurts SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'delivery_estimate' );

function delivery_estimate() {

   global $product;

   if ( 'product' == $product->post_type ) {

       $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'shipment-status' );

       if ( $terms instanceof WP_Error ) {
           // Log error here or whatever you need to do

       } elseif ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

           $term = $terms[ 0 ]; // assuming it is single-valued

           if ( 'available-in-ghana' == $term->slug ) {

               date_default_timezone_set( 'Africa/Accra' );  

               // if FRI/SAT/SUN delivery will be between +1 & +4 days
               if ( date( 'N' ) >= 5 ) {
                  $del_day = date( "j M", strtotime( "today + 1 day" ) );
                  $del_day2 = date( "j M", strtotime( "today + 4 day" ) );
                  $hour = gmdate("g", strtotime("tomorrow") - time()) . hrs;
                  $minutes = gmdate("i", strtotime("tomorrow") - time()) . mins;
                
                } 

               // if MON/THU after 4PM delivery will be day after tomorrow
               elseif ( date( 'H' ) >= 16 ) {
                  $del_day = date( "j M", strtotime( "tomorrow + 1 day" ) );
                  $hour = gmdate("g", strtotime("tomorrow") - time()) . hrs;
                  $minutes = gmdate("i", strtotime("tomorrow") - time()) . mins;
               } 

               // if MON/THU before 4PM delivery will be TOMORROW
               else {
                  $del_day = date( "j M", strtotime( "tomorrow" ) );
                  $hour = gmdate("g", strtotime("tomorrow") - time()) . hrs;
                  $minutes = gmdate("i", strtotime("tomorrow") - time()) . mins;
               }

               $html = "<br><div class='woocommerce-message' style='clear:both'>Order within the next $hour $minutes for delivery between {$del_day} & {$del_day2}</div>";

               echo $html;

        } // endif

    } // endif

}}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use WooCommerce's `global $product` you can get the taxonomy terms for the current product.  Then you should be able to display the right messages.

Your code will look something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'delivery_estimate' );

function delivery_estimate() {

   global $product;

   if ( 'YOUR_POST_TYPE' == $product->post_type ) {

       $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'YOUR_TAXONOMY_NAME' );

       if ( $terms instanceof WP_Error ) {
           // Log error here or whatever you need to do

       } elseif ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

           $term = $terms[ 0 ]; // assuming it is single-valued

           if ( 'YOUR_AVAILABLE_NOW_SLUG' == $term->slug ) {

               date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Tallinn' );  

               // if FRI/SAT/SUN delivery will be MON
               if ( date( 'N' ) >= 5 ) {
                  $del_day = date( "l jS F", strtotime( "next tuesday" ) );
                  $order_by = "Monday";
               } 

               // if MON/THU after 4PM delivery will be day after tomorrow
               elseif ( date( 'H' ) >= 16 ) {
                  $del_day = date( "l jS F", strtotime( "tomorrow + 1 day" ) );
                  $order_by = "tomorrow";
               } 

               // if MON/THU before 4PM delivery will be TOMORROW
               else {
                  $del_day = date( "2 jS F", strtotime( "tomorrow" ) );
                  $order_by = "today";
               }

               $html = "<br><div class='woocommerce-message' style='clear:both'>Order by 4PM {$order_by} for delivery on {$del_day}</div>";

               echo $html;

        } // endif

    } // endif

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you please help me with the changes as my knowledge of php is very basic.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. It works perfectly by showing to only the specified taxonomy however i would like the ***$del_day*** to be in the format eg ***4 Nov & 7 Nov*** i.e 3 days difference from the current day. So assuming the customer is viewing the page on the 3 Nov, it will show ***Ready for delivery between 4 Nov & 7 Nov when you order within 5h:30mins(hours left before the day ends)***

Comment: Okay i think am getting close to what i need.

I created a new variable ***$del_day2*** and updated the old variable and it now looks like 

`$del_day = date( "j M", strtotime( "today + 1 day" ) );
$del_day2 = date( "j M", strtotime( "today + 4 day" ) );`

Am now struggling to get ***$order_by*** to show the hours countdown left before the day will end.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean without seeing the code.  Maybe you need to create a new question or maybe something like this will help: [Calculate difference (in hours) between two times in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664870/calculate-difference-in-hours-between-two-times-in-php)

Comment: I figured how to output the hour and minutes left before 12am using `$order_by = gmdate("g:i", strtotime("tomorrow") - time());` How do i show the output time in the format ***7hrs 4mins*** instead of ***7:04*** ?